# Most efficient way in MySQL to retrieve values in a given week?

Tags: mysql, date-arithmetic

I need to produce a report that provides the count of each particular promotional code used within a particular week.  Example table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_promo_codes` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `promo_code` longtext NOT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

What I want is a count of each particular promo code used in a given week.  What I have right now:

```
SELECT promo_code, count(*) AS count
FROM user_promo_codes
WHERE last_updated BETWEEN
    FROM_UNIXTIME( # one week ago
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY ) ) - TIME_TO_SEC( NOW() )
    )
    AND
    FROM_UNIXTIME(
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() ) - TIME_TO_SEC( NOW() )
    )
GROUP BY value
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You *really* want to make the last_updated field an index. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data types you've shown, this should work fine for the week previous to *now*.

```
SELECT promo_code, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM user_promo_codes
WHERE last_updated BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY ) AND NOW()
GROUP BY promo_code
```

Asides:

- Using a `LONGTEXT` for the    `promo_code` will ensure a temp table    on disk. Likely best to make that a    `VARCHAR(N)`.
- As middaparka noted, an index on    `last_updated` will become invaluable    as the table grows.

**Update**

With `NOW()` -> the most recent Wedneday @ `00:00:00`.

```
SELECT promo_code, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM user_promo_codes
WHERE last_updated BETWEEN 
DATE_SUB( CONCAT( DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+5 DAY) ,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 7 DAY ) 
AND 
CONCAT( DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+5 DAY) ,' 00:00:00')
GROUP BY promo_code
```

Which is just the above with

```
CONCAT( DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+5 DAY) ,' 00:00:00')
```

swapped in for the `NOW()`s.

Comment: That's most of the way to what I need, but it's important that the endpoints of that BETWEEN clause be as I specified above. I can't guarantee that the script will be run in such a way that NOW() will always be midnight Wednesday morning.